# fill dgv in the background.

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have a dgv filled by a sp everything created with the wizard. since filling takes about 10 seconds i wanna have this in a background using a backgroundworker. I tried:

```
Public Class frmStart
Delegate Sub updateDGV()

Private Sub frmStart_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles MyBase.Load

    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Me.Invoke(New updateDGV(AddressOf UpdatingForm))

End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object , _
ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted

msgbox("Completed")

End Sub

Private Sub UpdatingForm()

    Try
        me.tableadapter.fill(me.dataset.table)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error during loading the dgv")
    Finally
        BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

I just see the first row in the dgv. How can i fill my whole dgv in the background, where is the mistake in the code? Additionally, i would like to see a popup during the fill process with "please wait your dgv gets filled". any idea how to accomplish that?

before i modified the code i had only the following line, which was programatically created.

```
me.tableadapter.fill(me.dataset.table)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new code is identical to the initial version. Me.Invoke is forcing UpdatingForm to be executed in UI thread. You can split in 2 parts.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Me.ProductsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.NorthwindDataSet.Products)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.ProductsBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
End Sub
```

check as well [Asynchronous Data Loading using TableAdapter with Cancel Feature](http://arsalantamiz.blogspot.ca/2008/09/asynchronous-data-loading-using.html)